# Javascript text input won't update based on 2D-array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, textbox

I am working on a React function to print a Sudoku board and allow the user to fill it in.

The function `printSudoku()` is used to return the board to the body of the webpage and display the contents. If a cell has been given a predefined value for the puzzle, the box is disabled to stop the user from editing the contents, otherwise it is accessible.

```
function printSudoku(puzzle){
    const board = puzzle[1];
    
    return (
      <div id="Puzzle-grid">
        {board.map((row, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            {row.map((cell, j) => (
              <input type="text" key={j} value={cell === '' ? userSolution[i][j]: cell} className="Puzzle-cell" disabled={cell !== ''}
              style={{backgroundColor: (((j < 3 || j >= 6) && (i < 3 || i >=6)) || (j >= 3 && j <6 && i >=3 && i < 6)) ? 'lightgray' : 'white', fontWeight: (cell !== '') ? 'bolder' : 'normal'}}
              onChange={(e) => updateUserSolution(e.target.value, i, j, userSolution)}/>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The next function is what is called upon change in an enabled cell, `updateUserSolution()`. This function takes the positioning of the cell from the Puzzle-grid and saves the contents to a 2D-array. This 2D-array is then used to overwrite the previous `userSolution` 2D-array with the new information.

```
function updateUserSolution(cell, rowIndex, colIndex, puzzle){
    const grid = userSolution;
    grid[rowIndex][colIndex] = cell;
    setUserSolution(grid);
    console.log(grid);
  }
```

The expected result is that the page will update to reflect the value of the userSolution 2D-array. However, the result is that the entered value is reflected in the 2D-array, but never in the table. I have tried other methods as well, such as using defaultValue for the given values and value only for the user input, which allows the input to be reflected, but results in issues upon generating a new puzzle. Any input would be greatly appreciated. If any further context is needed, I'd be happy to provide what I can.

Comment: I think you need to show us `setUserSolution()` as well; it seems that function would be updating the table, right?

Comment: My apologies, `setUserSolution()` is part of the useState declaration of the `userSolution` variable. Here is the declaration, but I don't know how much this will be as help. `const [userSolution, setUserSolution] = useState(puzzle[1].map(inner => inner.slice()));` Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'll admit I'm not familiar with react, but that doesn't seem like it would do anything to update a table. Are you referring to an html table to database table?

Comment: The array is a javascript variable. That is then supposed to be referenced to create a 9x9 grid of text inputs. The issue is that despite the `printSudoku()` function running upon the update of the `userSolution` variable, the values contained inside of the cells do not change.

Comment: Where do you call `printSudoku()`? Are you are passing the new array to it? And by "cells," do you mean the divs inside of `<div id="Puzzle-grid">`?

Comment: `printSudoku()` is called inside of the default `App` function, which is made up primarily of HTML. The value passed into it is a 2D-array with only certain values given to the user. I don't believe this should be causing the issue because to my knowledge, the function is correctly able to access the `userSolution` 2D-array as well since `printSudoku()` itself is defined inside of the `App` function.

Comment: You're modifying a state variable rather than creating a new one from scratch -> `grid[rowIndex][colIndex] = cell;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, you need to re-create any state objects/arrays that you want to be detected as modified.

```
function updateUserSolution(cell, rowIndex, colIndex, puzzle){
  setUserSolution(oldSolution => oldSolution.map((row, i) => 
    i === rowIndex ? 
      row.map((col, j) => j === colIndex ? 
        cell : 
        col
      )
      : row
  );
}
```